# Node.js & Memcache on Heroku ?

Tags: node.js, heroku, memcached

How do I use [Memcache](http://memcached.org/) (on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)) from a [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) service?

There is a [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache), explaining how to use Memcache from Ruby, Java and Python. I've asked this question on the Heroku mailing list with no results (my message seems to have been blocked or rejected).

Answer (score 4):

[MemJS](http://github.com/alevy/memjs) looks like a good candidate.

> MemJS is a pure Node.js client library for accessing the MemCachier service and other memcache servers. It uses the binary protocol and support SASL authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the steps in the Heroku Ruby tutorial (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache) to gain a basic understanding of how to interface with memcache on Heroku, but to do the same in node you should use the node-memcache library (https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache).

I hope this helps.

Comment: node-memcache won't work as you need a client that supports authentication. The MemJS library is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

node-memcache will not work with any of the memcache providers on Heroku. In particular, the library uses the text protocol, rather than the binary protocol and doesn't support SASL authentication. MemJS does both (as Jacob pointed out)